# How to type props for components that are nested in a HOC in Flow?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, flowtype

I came across that wrapping a component in a HOC doesn't return any type annotations.

Short example:

**components/Button/index.js**

```js
// @flow

import * as React from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Wrapper = styled.button`
  background-color: transparent;
`

type Props = {
  children?: React.Node,
  history: Object,
  target: String
}

const Button = (props: Props) => {
  return <Wrapper onClick={() => { if (props.target) props.history.push(props.target) }}>{props.children}</Wrapper>
}

export default withRouter(Button)
```

But VS Code doesn't give any information about my Button component when using this in another component:

[image]

That's how it should look:

[image]

So how do I have to write those type annotations?

## Update 1

So that's my current solution, based on the comments and some research (intersection of types):

```js
// @flow

import * as React from 'react'
import { RouterHistory, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import styled from 'styled-components'

import theme from 'themes/default'

type ButtonProps = {
  children: React.Node,
  target: string,
}

type Props = ButtonProps & RouterHistory

const Wrapper = styled.button`
  background-color: transparent;
`

const Button = ({ children, history, target }: Props) => (
  <Wrapper onClick={() => { history.push(target)}}>{children}</Wrapper>
)

const enhanced: typeof Button = withRouter(Button)
export default enhanced
```

I'm sure there are better solutions, but without the typed export, VS Code won't show any hints except `import Button`.

Comment: Probably you can `const enhanced: typeof Button = withRouter(Button); export default enhanced;`

Comment: Wow, jeah, thanks! Works like a charm :-)

Comment: The default export became `any` because flow doesn't know about the type of `withRouter` function. Probably the right way would be to install type definition of `react-router-dom` with flow-typed. https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed

Comment: I've installed flow-type and all the needed defs, but hovering over `Button` remains `import Button` without an further information. But hovering over `withRouter` shows the right type information.

Comment: Another problem are the definitions for my button: `withRouter` injects `history`, but I don't want to include this in my button props – because no one should pass `history` to this component.

Comment: Hmm, so the type definition from flow-typed is not good enough... I will write an answer that avoids using `withRouter` HOC.

Comment: I noticed one thing and updated the answer. I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the type of `Props` is wrong. With the type definition from flow-typed, `ContextRouter` is the type of the additional props that are provided by `withRouter` HOC.

```
import type { ContextRouter } from 'react-router';

type Props = ButtonProps & ContextRouter;
```

I made [an example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgWwA5wE4AuyYAhgM5gBKApiQMZFR5yZgDketDbA3KqsGBgAKgE9s1MABNqUdADt0BdHHkUmLMAAsCBbGQBcggOZKtAVwBGAOjotgsRAXHUH8BAFpnEqcEvxLYExyAmo8YBk5RWVVMmB5bExgTnoCD2ZzULwAfQA3ABZrAA9it0Q8gAZrAFYAZmKPZK40jKy8wpKSgCsyfhk6GBJOMG9JABk4OhIY+TAAXjAAb1QwMGxprXkSTGoDMDICPAVjABoV-do8Oi09g6P5U-Otchv9w+Oz1YPp6gB+PZI8lEnzAAGtqKJ-m97sZUABfPiofqDYajMATKYzADKzwk8yW53WBE22z+t3eDxBZEu1yhdw+TxedIpjy+BB+UMBonhiORQ0kaIAEugDvhRABBBgqWYLABEAAUAKpYwWysAAHzAssoAFF5WNxQBhHVqzUKgDy8tlvOoA35IxcVDgmTCwtFeFE+OWqxg1AexL28nMmEsYRB8Ex0r2GOm0pBqSjYDdBDFkpm4ZFoXkAApzqspjAYJZ6KC9tmI7HVNHJpX5CdSFKq0nM6nG-IAJTzAB8YFycHQUnO7bLnbmPb7A5B2HMZC02aJr3pDw16Jr2Nx1Hr31CnKBw97-akIM42EGdGo8425JhK5j65IEi37J3AL3ewnR-Oxjg2fkgeDoZ4PuH4gt+ABCJbZsBh6gXAABi+AIEMUhQe+MHnFM8gAOJwFCv7-iGYSjj2lhwHAvqAiC-iTKCuarPmJCFsWdClmA5Zromd5xg2Mx7MmrYzMRYCkeRtDyEOaGTucghgHQKShAAstQmBivxHrnAoMhFFCQaEXgIJ+u81BkFC4p4HgJCiAAPFxqhdjyfS2iiAqOgp0zXF6hJDNshhLGAADa4KiNexwALp7L8S7GGAcIgiKOpFKkewiRRdZeQG0IMqs5h4DAIUPA5SJOfaaKGqooRFAQlDOlkXrqk8LYens1UunganAucFa8aukaqCCwQENcexuYNWioOqCKOXawzUEUuCEGAUDmPIbZgAgZgtVkVnyl2dFgGVOCqIZzXNAAJAduDyIZYgSFZiyatYj1lfIFVVTVYZgI91jyhqcL2fuNCpOdLCXddLjbV2iJomBmQpvI8rMPonn5lo6AwFInB-lQzTWAAcnAMgguyeDGNQBD5Y8k2oGiCNwEjCww7oqi00jABk+3lbNb2tYidhqEQjNw-i2aLLJqPo5j9ao+6wIjEMpNEHCews2QQl7VZliw6oYCqIaMDoCxcyLFB3Z+dLKYetY06ztmxMK+2cJ-Ys1xoxjfpwlZfha-I-287ERA6vIzwrdQUiC9rCzrcSm1hNm4cdoiMmnQlEgMDq5n4KgVmB8H55h97YDAJDQA) on REPL.

**Alternative Approach**

HOC is hard to type in general because flow needs to **subtract** `history`, etc. from the props of `Button`. An alternative is ["render props" pattern](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html). It's much easier for flow to type-check because it doesn't require the subtraction.

Fortunately, [`withRouter`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/withRouter.js) is just a thin wrapper around `Route` component, which takes a `render` prop.

If you use `Route`, you can directly use `ButtonProps` and it's easier for flow to understand.

```
type ButtonProps = {
  children: React.Node,
  target: string,
}

const Button = ({ children, target }: ButtonProps) => (
  <Route
    render={({ history }) => (
      <button onClick={() => { history.push(target) }}>{children}</button>
    )}
  />
)

export default Button
```

I also made [a working example with render prop](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgWwA5wE4AuyYAhgM5gBKApiQMZFR5yZgDketDbA3KqsGBgAKgE9s1MABNqUdADt0BdHHkUmLMAAsCBbGQBcggOZKtAVwBGAOjotgsRAXHUH8BAFpnEqcEvxLYExyAmo8YBk5RWVVMmB5bExgTnoCD2ZzULwAfQA3ABZrAA9it0Q8gAZrAFYAZmKPZK40jKy8wpKSgCsyfhk6GBJOMG9JABk4OhIY+TAAXjAAb1QwMGxprXkSTGoDMDICPAVjABoV-do8Oi09g6P5U-Otchv9w+Oz1YPp6gB+PZI8lEnzAAGtqKJ-m97sZUABfPiofqDYajMATKYzADKzwk8yW53WBE22z+t3eDxBZEu1yhdw+TxedIpjy+BB+UMBonhiORQ0kaIAEugDvhRABBBgqWYLABEAAUAKpYwWysAAHzAssoAFF5WNxQBhHVqzUKgDy8tlvOoA35IxcVDgmTCwtFeFE+OWqxg1AexL28nMmEsYRB8Ex0r2GOm0pBqSjYDdBDFkpm4ZFoXkAApzqspjAYJZ6KC9tmI7HVNHJpX5CdSFKq0nM6nG-IAJTzAB8YFycHQUnO7bLnbmPb7A5B2HMZC02aJr3pDw16Jr2Nx1Hr31CnKBw97-akIM42EGdGo8425JhK5j65IEi37J3AL3ewnR-Oxjg2fkgeDoZ4PuH4gt+ABCJbZsBh6gXAABi+AIEMUhQe+MHnFM8gAOJwFCv7-iGYSjj2lhwHAvqAiC-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) with REPL.

Comment: Oh, yes, it has to be `ContextRouter`. But this example still needs to type the export. But the alternative approach works fine and looks thousand times better!